# Tailwind Border not working in Angular prject. Computed as 0px even though it says 4px

Tags: angular, border, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I can never get the tailwind borders to work. When I inspect it, it says there's 4px, but when I go to Computed, it says 0px. I don't know what's overriding it. I don't have a CSS file, so it's not that.

```
  <h2 class="text-center">Angular Training</h2>
  <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-10 mt-6">
    <div class="w-4/5">
      <h4>Public Angular Training</h4>
      <div class="border border-l-4 border-indigo-500">
        <p>
          Buy a ticket for our live, instructor-led, <b>online</b>
          classes. Ask questions, get help, and workshop your code in real-time.
        </p>
        <p>
          <img
            class="float-right pt-5 ml-1"
            alt="map"
            src="assets/images/map2small.png"
            width="150"
          />Or, attend Angular Boot Camp <b>in-person</b> in
          <abc-cities></abc-cities>
          and others.
        </p>
      </div>
```

[Entire page showing where it should be and how big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRnJ4.jpg)

[Computed to 0px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpNAr.png)

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem: You are using `border` together with `border-l-4`

Use only `border-l-4`:

```html
  <div class="border-l-4 border-indigo-500">
```

Hovering the class should tell you what styles are applying.

[image]

Comment: My issue is that I can't Only have a left border. This creates a border around the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your whole code, but it looks like you could be missing the **border-style** property.

In Tailwind:

```
border-solid
```

[Tailwind - Border Style](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-style)

Comment: This creates a border around the whole thing. I only want a border on the left side. While this does make the left side thicker, It adds a thin line everywhere else.

Comment: Remove the  `border` class. The `border` class adds a 1px border on each side. If you **only** want the left side, do `border-l-4 border-indigo-500 border-solid`